# $Var(X-Y)$ strange outcome

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> THe time $Y$ between the arrival of two jobs has the probabilitiy density
>
> $$
> f(y) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-\dfrac{y}{2}}
> $$
>   The duration, $Z \sim Unif[1,3]$ and is **independent** of Y
>
> Assume that it is difficult to determine the probability densities of $Y$ and $Z$ and that one only has information about the expectations and the variances of $Y$ and $Z$. Give an upp[er bound for $P(Z>Y+3)$ that is strictly smaller than 1.

now the solution states:
$$
P(Z\geq Y+3) \leq P(|Z-Y|\geq 3)
$$
since we only have information on the expected values and variances of $Y$ and $Z$, we use the Chebyshev inequality for $U=Z-Y$. it holds that $E(Z-Y)=0$ and that $var(Z-Y) = 13/3$

now my proble is with the $\frac{13}{3}$, since

$$
Var(Z-Y) = Var(Z)+Var(Y) 
$$
Since X and Y are independent, filling that in since  $Y \sim EXP(\frac{1}{2})$ 
$$
\begin{align}
Var(Z-Y)&= Var(Z) +  Var(Y)\\
&= \dfrac{(3-1)^2}{12} + \frac{1^2}{2^2}
\\ &= \frac{4}{12} + \frac{3}{12} 
\\ &= \frac{7}{12}
\end{align}
$$

Is the answer givin in the answers wrong? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spotted the mistake, it should have been 
$$
\dfrac{4}{12}  + \dfrac{48}{12} = \dfrac{52}{12} = \dfrac{13}{3}  
$$

because if $X\sim exp(\frac{1}{\theta})$ then $var(X) = \theta^2$, not $(\frac{1}{\theta})^2$